# Добавить DataFrame в Excel файл, не перезаписывая его

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Код:

```
print(resDF.head(100))
if self.Config["checkFile"] == 'D:\\git\\validator\\testData\\csv\\catalog_test.csv':
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors_Catalog.xlsx')
    resDF.to_excel(writer, "Catalog", index=False)
    writer.save()
elif self.Config["checkFile"] == 'D:\\git\\validator\\testData\\csv\\clientfull_test.CSV':
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors_Clients.xlsx')
    resDF.to_excel(writer, "Clients", index=False)
    writer.save()
elif self.Config["checkFile"] == 'D:\\git\\validator\\testData\\csv\\items_test.csv':
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors_Items.xlsx')
    resDF.to_excel(writer, "Items", index=False)
    writer.save()
elif self.Config["checkFile"] == 'D:\\git\\validator\\testData\\csv\\sales_test.csv':
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors_Sales.xlsx')
    resDF.to_excel(writer, "Sales", index=False)
    writer.save()
elif self.Config["checkFile"] == 'D:\\git\\validator\\testData\\csv\\shop_test.csv':
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors_Shops.xlsx')
    resDF.to_excel(writer, "Shops", index=False)
    writer.save()
elif self.Config["checkFile"] == 'D:\\git\\validator\\testData\\csv\\delivery_test.csv':
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors_Catalog.xlsx')
    resDF.to_excel(writer, "Catalog", index=False)
    writer.save()
```

У меня есть некоторое кол-во файлов, которые проходят проверку по некоторым алгоритмам. Итог проверки каждого файла выводится в консоль и создается отдельный файл Excel.
А хотелось бы, чтобы это писалось не в разные файлы, а в один, просто на разные листы.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Оформите код нормально, поясните, что он делает и что вы хотите получить, и что означает «зациклить метод»

Comment: "отличный" антипример оформления вопроса... Советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Что Вы хотите - не понять при такой постановке вопроса. 
Но зациклить что-то можно так:
while True:
    print(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Pandas 1.4.0 [параметр `if_sheet_exists` в классе `ExcelWriter()` планируют расширить таким образом, чтобы он принимал значение 'overlay'](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L800-L814), которое будет позволять дозаписывать DataFrame в существующий лист Excel файла, не перезаписывая его содержимого. Таким образом в будущих версиях Pandas эта функциональность будет поддерживаться "из коробки".

---

Для того, чтобы добавить DataFrame в существующий Excel файл не перезаписав его, [можно воспользоваться следующей функцией](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205):

PS данная функция позволяет записывать DataFrame как в существующий лист (`Sheet`) так и в новый.

Примеры использования:

```
append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df)

append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, header=None, index=False)

append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)

append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False, startrow=25)
```

Comment: А возможно ли ещё добавить вывод даты и времени?

Comment: @ФедорАндреевичПривалов, куда добавить? как? лучше задайте отдельный вопрос с небольшим примером того, что хотите получить...