# Что за keyword 'mode', Как выгружать pandas dataframe в csv чтобы не было проблем с кодировкой или как выгружать сразу xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
import vk_api
import pandas as pd
import time
import json

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('******', '*******')  # логин и пароль
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def main():


    count_in = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='******')
    count = count_in['count']
    print(count)
    offset = 0

    i = 0
    step = 1000

    for count in range(count_in['count'], 0, -step):
        y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='******', offset=i * step,fields='contacts')
        time.sleep(3)
        data = y
        df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['items'])
        df.to_csv(r'********.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=(i == 0), encoding='utf8')
        i += 1




if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Дело в том, что когда я открываю выгруженый csv в Линукс, никаких поблем нет, но если это Windows или Mac OS, то у меня проблемы с кодировкой. Если я делаю `df.to_excel`, то вылетает ошибка, что у excel модуля нет ключевого слова mode.

За что вообще отвечает этот параментр? И есть ли его эквивалент для Excel?
Kак лучше решить эту проблему? Написать отдельно конвертер? Если да, то как это реализовать для большого количества CSV файлов? Или может экспортировать сразу в Excel xlsx файл? И как это реализуется?

Дело в том что по мере прохождения итераций цикла данные должы дозаписываться в файл, а не перезаписывать его.

Comment: `mode` -- это режим открытия файла `'********.csv'`. Если `mode='w'`, значит файл будет перезаписан новыми данными, если же `'a'` -- новые данные добавятся в конец файла (есть и другие значения mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `.to_excel()` не позволяет дописывать/добавлять данные в существующий Excel файл. Это можно сделать воспользовавшись [данной функцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819305/211923).

Также можно собрать все данные в один список, преобразовать его в DataFrame и сохранить его как Excel файл:

```
step = 1000
data = []

for count in range(count_in['count'], 0, -step):
    y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_public', offset=offset,
                             fields='contacts')
    data.append(y['items'])
    time.sleep(3)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
df.to_excel(r'resulting_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

---

**UPDATE:** судя по опубликованному файлу данные надо собирать немного иначе:

```
step = 1000
data = []

for count in range(count_in['count'], 0, -step):
    y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_public', offset=offset,
                             fields='contacts')
    #data += y['items']
    data.extend(y['items'])
    time.sleep(3)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
df.to_excel(r'resulting_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudsurfer/PycharmProjects/PyVkParser/vk_parsing_numbers_v3.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cloudsurfer/PycharmProjects/PyVkParser/vk_parsing_numbers_v3.py", line 35, in main
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
  File "/home/cloudsurfer/PycharmProjects/PyVkParser/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py", line 193, in json_normalize
    for x in compat.itervalues(y)] for y in data]):

Comment: File "/home/cloudsurfer/PycharmProjects/PyVkParser/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
    for x in compat.itervalues(y)] for y in data]):
  File "/home/cloudsurfer/PycharmProjects/PyVkParser/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 211, in itervalues
    return iter(obj.values(**kw))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @CloudSurferCode, вы можете выложить куда-нибудь значение получившегося `data` на котором вываливается эта ошибка?