# Вставить строку с данными словаря в Excel файл

Tags: python, pandas, pyside2

Есть Excel файл в котором находится 22 столбца, а количество строк изначально 0.

Пример файла:

```
id col1 col2 col3  ...

1  sds  dsd  sdsd  ...
2  saa  asd  asda  ...
3  dsd  sds  dsds  ...
.  ...  ...  ....
```

Не получается вставить в данный файл строку данные словаря. Значения словаря соответствуют значению строки в приложении собраного с помощью Pyside2:

```
main_dict = {
'id' : 23 , 
'col1' : 'some_date' , 
'col2' : 'some_date',
'col3' : 'some_date'}
```

То есть, ключи словаря это столбцы Excel файла.

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Код который я использую (отступы соблюдены):

```
def insert_data():
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx' , sheet_name= 'Sheet1' )
# print(df)

data = []
index = []

main_dict = {
'id' : 23 , 
'col1' : 'some_data' , 
'col2' : 'some_data',
'col3' : 'some_data' , 
'col4' : 'some_data',
'col5' : 'some_data', 
'col6' : 'some_data' ,
'col7' : 'some_data',
'col8' : 'some_data', 
'col9' : 'some_data',
'col10' : 'some_data', 
'col11' : 'some_data' , 
'col12' : 'some_data', 
'col13' : 'some_data', 
'col14' : 'some_data' , 
'col15' : 'some_data', 
'col16' : 'some_data', 
'col17' : 'some_data', 
'col18' : 'some_data' , 
'col19' : 'some_data', 
'col20' : 'some_data', 
'col21' : 'some_data', 
}

data.append(list(main_dict.values()))
index.append(main_dict['id'])

new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=main_dict.keys(), index=index)
res = df.append(new)
```

Comment: не понимаю вот эту часть вопроса: `"вставить в данный файл строку данные словарь"` - можете сформулировать понятнее? А еще лучше привести пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: В примере я указал словарь.
Необходимо этот словарь вставить в ексель файл. значения словаря это должны быть строки, а ключ словаря это должен быть столбец

Comment: вы добавили данные в DataFrame, но где код в котором вы записываете этот DF в Excel файл?

Comment: df.append(new) разве не вставляет новую строку в ексель

Comment: нет, эта команда добавляет DataFrame `new` к  DataFrame `df`

Comment: подскажите и как написать код что бы добавить строку

Comment: чтобы добавить DataFrame в Excel файл: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981694/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-pandas-%d0%b2-excel?noredirect=1#comment1651819_981706

Comment: Всё равно выводит ошибку , код взял из ниже указанного примера по ссылке

Comment: По-моему, лучше открыть отдельный вопрос и привести в нем код и полный текст ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   id col1 col2 col3
0   1  aaa  bbb  ccc
1   2  aa2  bb2  cc2

In [8]: list(main_dict.values())
Out[8]: [23, 'some_date', 'some_date', 'some_date']
```

Добавляем строку в DF:

```
In [9]: df.loc[main_dict['id']] = list(main_dict.values())

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
    id       col1       col2       col3
0    1        aaa        bbb        ccc
1    2        aa2        bb2        cc2
23  23  some_date  some_date  some_date
```

Но гораздо эффективнее будет собрать сразу все значения, которые мы хотим добавить, в список списков и добавить все это одной командой:

```
data = []
index = []

main_dict = {
    'id' : 23 , 
    'col1' : 'some_date' , 
    'col2' : 'some_date',
    'col3' : 'some_date'}
data.append(list(main_dict.values()))
index.append(main_dict['id'])

main_dict = {
    'id' : 24, 
    'col1' : 'some_date_2', 
    'col2' : 'some_date_2',
    'col3' : 'some_date_2'}
data.append(list(main_dict.values()))
index.append(main_dict['id'])

new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=main_dict.keys(), index=index)

res = df.append(new)
```

---

```
In [20]: res
Out[20]:
    id         col1         col2         col3
0    1          aaa          bbb          ccc
1    2          aa2          bb2          cc2
23  23    some_date    some_date    some_date
24  24  some_date_2  some_date_2  some_date_2
```

Comment: не отрабатывает не один из выше указанных методов

Comment: @WilteRatenau, что значит не отрабатывает? Какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: никакие просто файл по прежнему пустой

Comment: @WilteRatenau, [Добавить DataFrame в Excel файл, не перезаписывая его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819240/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-dataframe-%D0%B2-excel-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Comment: не совсем понимаю как это решает мою проблему.

Comment: @WilteRatenau, можете привести в вопросе код, в котором вы добавляете данные в DataFrame и где дописываете этот DF в Excel файл?