# Ошибка при вставке в Excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

```
def append_df_to_excel('file_name.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False, 
                       **to_excel_kwargs):

# print(df)

data = []
index = []

main_dict = {
'id' : 23 , 
'col1' : 'some_data' , 
'col2' : 'some_data',
'col3' : 'some_data' , 
'col4' : 'some_data',
'col5' : 'some_data', 
'col6' : 'some_data' ,
'col7' : 'some_data',
'col8' : 'some_data', 
'col9' : 'some_data',
'col10' : 'some_data', 
'col11' : 'some_data' , 
'col12' : 'some_data', 
'col13' : 'some_data', 
'col14' : 'some_data' , 
'col15' : 'some_data', 
'col16' : 'some_data', 
'col17' : 'some_data', 
'col18' : 'some_data' , 
'col19' : 'some_data', 
'col20' : 'some_data', 
'col21' : 'some_data', 
}

data.append(list(main_dict.values()))
index.append(main_dict['id'])

new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=main_dict.keys(), index=index)
res = df.append(new)

data.append(list(main_dict.values()))
index.append(main_dict['id'])

new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=main_dict.keys(), index=index)
res = df.append(new)




if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
    to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    try:
    writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
    if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

    if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
        writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
        writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)
    writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

if startrow is None:
    startrow = 0

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)
writer.save()
```

Выдаёт ошибку сначало на

> ```
> def append_df_to_excel('file_name.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
>                                          ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ```
> to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')
>                               ^
> ```
>
> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: откройте ваш код в редакторе, ктороый умеет показывать табуляции и замените все табуляции на пробелы

Comment: не помогло. выдаёт ошибку всё ту же

Comment: совет: создайте функцию из [этого ответа как есть ничего в ней не меняя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819305/211923) и попробуйте с ней поработать дописывая DataFrame к существующему Excel файлу...

Comment: помогло. Вставка произошла.
однако вставляет начиная не с столбца "А" а со стобца "Б". и не значения из словарь а ключи.