# openpyxl как записать информацию в файл excel без перезаписи старой информации

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

С помощью openpyxl легко записать информацию в exel, но при активации Workbook openpyxl перезаписывает все, что находится в листе и оставляет только новую информацию (Пример ниже). Единственный вариант, который приходит в голову это: открыть файл exel с нужной информацией в режиме чтения, записать ее в переменную и добавить в эту переменную новую информацию (тем самым объединив старую с новой), затем открыть файл exel в режиме записи и перезаписать всю информацию. Будет круто, если подскажете как избежать таких манипуляций и покажете способ, которым можно дописать в нужную ячейку(ки) информацию, не удаляя ничего с других ячеек.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font, Side
from datetime import  *

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = 'testexel'

td = datetime.today()
td = td.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %S:%M:%H')

ws['A6'] = 2345
ws['B6'] = td
wb.save('exel.xlsx')
```

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819240/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-dataframe-%d0%b2-excel-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае достаточно заменить wb = Workbook() на wb = load_workbook('exel.xlsx'):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font, Side
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import  *

wb = load_workbook('exel.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws.title = 'testexel'

td = datetime.date.today()
td = td.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %S:%M:%H')

ws['A6'] = 2345
ws['B6'] = td
wb.save('exel.xlsx')
```