# Как записывать данные в уже имеющийся эксель файл с помощью pandas и xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
Запись файла выглядит так, а как можно реализовать дозапись в этот файл?

for i in range(len(data_1)):
    data_1[i].update(data_2[i])
    data_1[i].update(data_3[i])
df = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('tableALL.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819305/211923

Answer (score 0):

судя по [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

```
class pandas.ExcelWriter(path, engine=None, date_format=None, datetime_format=None, mode='w', **engine_kwargs)
```

значит вот так.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('tableALL.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', mode='a')
```

Comment: ошибка, xlsxwriter не поддерживает append, значит так просто не выдет