# Создание столбцов в Excel таблице

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Парсю информацию с сайта. Спарсил, допустим, 5 названий. Нужно создать 5 столбцов в Excel и записать название в каждый из столбцов.

Как это реализловать?

Допустим, 5 городов:

```py
lst = ['Москва', 'Питер', 'Уфа', 'Смоленск', 'Омск']
```

И 5 столбцов: город 1, город 2 и т.д., таблица будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: использовать модуль для работы с экселем.

Comment: С помощью модуля csv как ?

Comment: На сколько мне известно Numpy умеет общаться с Excel

Comment: Если приведете пример данных в вопросе, то я мог бы набросать рабочий пример - как это делается в Pandas...

Comment: Посмотрите изменения

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот

Comment: как еще конкретней, есть список в  нем города, что непонятного ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример для данных из **одной** строки:

```
lst = ['Москва', 'Питер', 'Уфа', 'Смоленск', 'Омск']

df = pd.DataFrame([lst], columns=[f"город {i+1}" for i in range(len(lst))])

df.to_excel(r"c:\temp\result.xlsx", index=False)
```

---

Пример для данных, состоящих из **двух и более** строк, данные задаются в виде списка кортежей/списков, где каждый элемент списка задает одну строку фрейма:

```
data = [
  ('Москва', 'Питер', 'Уфа', 'Смоленск', 'Омск'),
  (10, 11, 9, 8, 20)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f"город {i+1}" for i in range(len(lst))])
```

---

результат:

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
  город 1 город 2 город 3   город 4 город 5
0  Москва   Питер     Уфа  Смоленск    Омск
1      10      11       9         8      20
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

data = {
  "город 1": ["Москва", "100"],
  "город 2": ["Питер", "110"],
  "город 3": ["Уфа", "120"],
  "город 4": ["Смоленск", "130"],
  "город 5": ["Омск", "140"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel(r"c:\temp\result.xlsx", index=False)
```

---

**NOTE:** в SO вопросах, связанных с обработкой данных, ключевую роль играют примеры входных и выходных данных и структуры, в которых эти данные хранятся!

Посудите сами - если задающий вопрос не указывает как именно он(а) хранит данные то и дать рабочий и проверенный ответ на это практически невозможно. Ведь данные могут быть в виде необработанного текста, Excel / PDF / Word / JSON / etc. файла, в виде списка кортежей/списков, в виде словаря со списками, в виде списка словарей и т.д. Вариаций может быть очень много. Невозможно дать **универсальный** и проверенный ответ. На неточный и "размытый" вопрос можно получить только неточный и "размытый" ответ.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы программа была универсальной. Например, на 1 странице 5 городов нужно заполнить 5 столбцов, на 2 странице уже 3 города нужно  заполнить только 3 столбца

Comment: @Ylanaish, именно поэтому я и спрашивал о примерах данных! Как вы собираете данные и в каких структурах вы их храните? Есди вы будете __динамически__ создавать словарь с данными, то все будет замечательно работать)

Comment: храню в виде списка

Comment: @Ylanaish, вы читали ссылку, которую я привел в комментах? `"храню в виде списка"` - никакой конкретики. При таких входных данных - максимум, на который стоит расчитывать - это ответы типа - `создайте Pandas DataFrame из списка`. Если такие общие ответы вас устроят, то можете и дальше приводить такие "примеры данных" ;)

Comment: А как в уже созданный файл добавить столбцы? Посмотрите изменения

Comment: в этот файл добавить столбцы с городами

Comment: @Ylanaish, проще всего сначала собрать все данные, которые вы хотите записать в Excel файл в один список и потом создать из него фрейм

Comment: Есть возможность дописывать файл?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109289/discussion-between-maxu-and-ylanaish).

Comment: @Ylanaish, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819305/211923