# Как убрать перезаписывание файла Excel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Я обучаюсь библиотеке pandas. Возникает вопрос с работой в Excel:

**Как сделать так, чтобы файл не перезаписывался, а продолжался** - Если прописать следующие строки:

```
#Сохранение в Ексель
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("questions.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

то всё сохранится. Но если запустить скипт во второй раз, результат, занесённый ранее перезапишется. Я много смотрел в интернете решение, но найти ничего не могу, точнее, не понимаю. Вопрос закрывали и давали ссылку на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819240/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-dataframe-%D0%B2-excel-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE), но даже в том вопросе, я ничего не понял.

Вот мой код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


question = int(input("Введите цифру. Она будет использоваться первым числом: "))
ones = np.ones(1)
result = ones + question

df = pd.DataFrame ({ #Содаём таблицу
     "question": question,
     "answer": result
})

#Сохранение в Ексель
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("questions.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, index= False)
writer.save()

#Вывод таблицы
print(df)

questionTotal = pd.read_excel('questions.xlsx')
questionTotal.head()
print(questionTotal)
```

Comment: Логично в том вопросе и задать уточняющие вопросы. Что значит "ничего не понял" в отношении к совету " Используйте функцию append_df_to_excel? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент (версия 1.3.5) Pandas "из коробки" не позволяет дозаписывать (**без перезаписи**) DataFrame в существующий лист Excel файла.

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [append_df_to_excel()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205), которая как раз создана для того, чтобы дозаписывать DataFrame в существующий лист Excel файла, сохраняя прежнюю информацию (без перезаписи).

PS в Pandas 1.4.0 параметр `if_sheet_exists` в классе [ExcelWriter()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L800-L814) планируют расширить таким образом, чтобы он принимал значение `'overlay'`, которое будет позволять дозаписывать DataFrame в существующий лист Excel файла, не перезаписывая его содержимого. Таким образом в будущих версиях Pandas эта функциональность будет поддерживаться "из коробки".